# C++: wrong template function overload selection

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, eigen, lazy-evaluation

I would like to implement some lazy evaluation in my code. Here is a snippet representative of what I would like to do:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

template <int N, int M>
struct S {
  template <typename T>
  S &operator=(const T &src) {
    v = src();
    return *this;
  }

  Eigen::Matrix<double, N, M> v;
};

// If I comment this one the code compiles
template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
auto operator+(const Lhs &lhs, const Rhs &rhs) {
  return [&]() { return lhs() + rhs(); };
}

template <typename Lhs, int N, int M>
auto operator+(const Lhs &lhs, const S<N, M> &s) {
  return [&]() { return lhs() + s.v; };
}

template <typename Rhs, int N, int M>
auto operator+(const S<N, M> &s, const Rhs &rhs) {
  return [&]() { return s.v + rhs(); };
}

template <int N0, int M0, int N1, int M1>
auto operator+(const S<N0, M0> &s0, const S<N1, M1> &s1) {
  return [&]() { return s0.v + s1.v; };
}

int main() {
  static constexpr int n = 4;
  S<n, n> s0, s1;
  S<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> s2;

  s1.v = 2. * Eigen::Matrix<double, n, n>::Ones();
  s2.v = 3. * Eigen::Matrix<double, n, n>::Ones();

  s0 = s1 + s2;

  std::cout << s0.v << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I got a compilation error which relates to the fact that when implementing `s1 + s2`, the first overload of the `+` operator is selected (and if I comment it, the code works). It seems that for the compiler the first one is considered as the more specialized, whereas to my common sense the last one is the more specialized: the first one accepts whatever arguments, whereas the last one only accepts type related to the template class `S`.

What is the explanation to that? How can I fix this snippet to make it work while keeping the first overload (which will be required for the lazy evaluation of 'nested' expressions)?

Many thanks!

**EDIT: from the answer and comments, I now understand that the problem is related to a conflict between the first overload of the + operator in the snippet and the some overload of the + operator in the Eigen library**. The simplified snippet following illustrate that:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
auto operator+(const Lhs &lhs, const Rhs &rhs) {
  return [&]() { return lhs() + rhs(); };
}

int main() {
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> m0, m1, m2;
  m2=m0+m1;
  return 0;
}
```

Here, the + operator of the snippet is selected, whereas I expected that one of the Eigen's would be selected... Why is that?

Comment: Unconstrainted `operator+` is indeed dangerous.

Comment: Presumably `Eigen::Dynamic` is `-1` or at least an integer that can't be misinterpreted as a column count

Comment: @Jarod42 I get the fact that the first overload catches everything, and so 'pollutes' the whole namespace it is defined into. But being so generic I would expect him not to be selected in this case... Also, do you see a trick to do lazy evaluation without defining such 'generic' operator?

Comment: @janou195: "in this case" - _which_ case? `return s0.v + s1.v;` or `s0 = s1 + s2;` ?

Comment: `requires(requires (lhs() + rhs()))` would be a good first step.

Comment: @Jarod42: I'm not entirely certain if that works as intended, because Eigen also has an `operator()`. I think a custom named concept `LazyEvaluable` would make more sense here.

Comment: @MSalters: Issue is that OP returns lambda: so `(s1+s1)+(s1+s1)` no longer use custom types.

Comment: BTW, Eigen already uses template expression.

Comment: @Jarod42 `requires(requires (lhs() + rhs()))` seems to be c++20. The code I am working on is in c++17. Is there an equivalent c++17 way?

Comment: You might do that with SFINAE... but I strongly suggest to use your own type instead of relying on lambda.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first overload is selected, but not for `s1 + s2`. That selects the 4th overload. However, inside that 4th overload you have `s0.v + s1.v;`, and `.v` is **not** an `S<N, M>`

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What do you mean by 'the first overload is selected, but not for s1 + s2'? Also I am not sure to understand what you mean in your 2nd sentence...

Comment: @janou195: You are correctly noticing that the first overload is selected in the code above, because removing it makes a difference. You are incorrectly assuming that is it selected for the line `s0 = s1 + s2;`. That line instead instantiates the 4th overload. In turn, the instantiation contains `s0.v + s1.v;`, which _again_ requires overload resolution of `operator+`. And **now** it matters whether you commented out the first overload.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point! My interpretation was wrong. But now my problem is that: why my operator is selected instead of the Eigen ones at the spot `s0.v + s1.v`? I wil edit my question in this sense!